# How to get values separated by a delimiter from a column separately using SQL

Tags: sql, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table 'spotify' in Snowflake like:

| SONG | SINGER | rankA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Medallo | Blessd \ Justin Quiles | 10 |
| FRIKI | Fied \ Karol G | 2 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

Now, I want to print all the singers whose song have rank less than 5, so I do the following command;

```sql
select SINGER from spotify  where rankA < 5;
```

This gives me

| SINGER |
| --- |
| Fied \ Karol G |

I expect a list where all singers are separated by '\', like this:

`Fied`

`Karol G`

I could not figure how to use string split here in Snowflake worksheet, and if there is any other method or workaround for the same.

I basically need the singer names separated from the delimiter '\'

Comment: Can you share why the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html) are not clear ?  (What did you try, where did it brake?)

Comment: @Luuk , i restricted myself to looking at string split from SQL to use in snowflake. Checked this [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html) and now used the flatten function with split and it works perfectly ! Thankyou !

Comment: When working with snowflake, I would stick to their docs.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

as a dirty hack i would do this:

```
select split_part(regexp_replace('foo \ bar',' \\ ','<delimiter>'),'<delimiter>',0);
```

I was unable to use split_part on a backslash.
This first changes your backslash into  keywordand then splits the string based it. This will not return correct results if string '' is in your original string, aka if there is a singer with name